# Connect to a socket.io node.js server from a node.js console program

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Let me explain the setup a bit more. I have socket.io running inside a node.js server.

I want to connect to this server from another node.js program that is running in the console (outside the browser).

All examples that I have seen so far only talk about a socket.io client that is running inside a browser, but I want to connect to a console program which is outside the browser.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem, use `socket.io-client`

more info here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client

Comment: Damn.. I don't know how I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: make sure to also check out engine.io, which is socket.io's underlying communication layer if you just want to abstract WebSocket communication